# while loop with if statement not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

hi i have the following while loop :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){

    $elem_filho = $row['itempt_dim'];

    $marcas = "{name: " . "'" . $elem_filho . "'" . ", color: " . "'" . $cor_alea . "'" . ", size: 1";

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2)) {
      $dif = "},";
    }

    else {
      $dif = "}]";
    }

    $vlk = $marcas . $dif;
    print_r($vlk);

  }
```

the thing is i had similar code and it worked this way, but the output is alway }, and i want the last item of the query to end with }] 
i can't see what i am doing wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: As you are retrieving rows from the result set, `mysqli_num_rows($result2)` will always be > 0 and that is why you always get `}`.  If you are trying to build JSON - build it using arrays and `json_encode()`

Comment: what can i do to get to the desired result ?

Comment: Not 100% sure if it will work (you will actually end up with `},]` would be to just add `echo "]";` after the loop (and remove the `if`)

Comment: `json_encode` __already invented__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `json_encode` you code is simplified to:

```
$vlk = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $vlk[] = [
        'name' => $row['itempt_dim'],
        'color' => $cor_alea,
        'size' => 1,
    ];
}
print_r(json_encode($vlk));
```